# C# Assign a Variable to a Class call

Tags: c#

Lets say I have a namespace GPS, where I can call stuff like GPS.devise.coordinates.getLoc, that would simply return the GPS coords of my devise.

How can i assign all that "GPS.devise.coordinates" verbose to a variable such as "Me"?

So I could do Me.getLoc instead.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming getLoc() is static, try using the following:

```
using Me = GPS.devise.coordinates;
```

This is often used for shortening namespaces where the classes have common names.  A great example to check out would be the VSTO libraries, where most of the namespaces have an Application class.

Answer (score 2):

You could expose a property that returned it, like this:

```
 public Point getLoc { get { return this.device.coordinates.getLoc;}}
```

Comment: That would not be a particularly good API design if the getLoc method returns a new value every time it is called (as I suspect it might). A property is expected to return the same object every time it is invoked.

Comment: In addition to marks comment is a property expected to return immediately. Calling GetLoc can potentially result in a long running method.

Answer (score 0):

what class would 'Me' be?

if 'Me' was say a Person class

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(){}

    private GPS _gps = new GPS();
    public Coords getLoc
    {
        get{
            return _gps.devise.coordinates.getLoc;
        }
    }
}


Person Me = new Person;
Coords MyLocation = Me.getLoc;
```

Answer (score 0):

If `getLoc` is a property, you can simply do this:

```
var me = GPS.devise.coordinates.getLoc;
```

However, I suspect that since you are asking, `getLoc` is a method. In that case, you can assign the method group to a delegate. In C# 3.0 you can do this:

```
var me = () => GPS.devise.coordinates.getLoc();
```

which would enable you to get the coordinates like this:

```
var coordinates = me();
```

An alternative declaration of `me` would be this:

```
Func<Coords> me = GPS.devise.coordinates.getLoc;
```

assuming that the return type of `getLoc` is `Coords`.

Those two declarations of `me` amounts to the same thing - it's just two different ways of writing it.

---

If you simply want a shorthand for `coordinates` because it has more than one method you'd like to invoke it would be very simple. Although I can't tell from your example whether `coordinates` is a field or a property, it doesn't matter because in both cases you simply assign the object to a new variable:

```
var coords = GPS.devise.coordinates;
```

Subsequently you can then invoke methods on the `coords` variable:

```
var loc = coords.getLoc();
var satTime = coords.getSatTime();
```

etc.

This will work with any version of C# (even 1.0) with the slight modification that instead of `var` you would need to explicitly declare the type of the variable. `var` is a C# 3.0 (Visual Studio 2008) feature.

Comment: What if the GPS.devise.coordinates, had more methods? 

I wanted something like :
GPS.devise.coordinates Me;

As a proxy for GPS.devise.coordinates, such as :

Me.GetLoc
Me.GetSatTime
Me.etc

Instead of 
GPS.devise.coordinates.getLoc
GPS.devise.coordinates.getSatTime
GPS.devise.coordinates.etc

Comment: I've edited the answer to address your additional question. Hope this helps.

Comment: Error 1 'GPS.devise.coordinates' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

When i hover it, it says its a class.

Also, does not allow me to use var in a public manner, to be accessible from all methods.

I need it as a shorthand, yes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is 'GPS.devise.coordinates' the full type name of the class, or is it a nested type?

Comment: I must admit that I know longer understand the scenario. Is GPS as type or is GPS.devise.coordinates a type? Your comment seems to contradict your original question. I will need more details if I shall be able to help. You can edit your original question to add more details if you like.

Comment: coordinates is a class, nested.
getLoc i am not sure if its a method or a setter getter.

Comment: You should be able to assign it to a variable, then.

Comment: I dont know if you did understand, but I want a shorthand for GPS.devise.coordinates, so I can then call methods directly on that shorthand, as I sayed on the original question.

Instead of GPS.devise.coordinates.getLoc()
write Me.getLoc()
Me pointing to GPS.devise.coordinates or something.

Since i dont want to write GPS.devise.coordinates 600 times, when I could just call Me

Was I clear? :/

Comment: It would be exactly like your example :
var coords = GPS.devise.coordinates;
coords.getLoc();

But I cant seem to declare it in the "public" (?) area of the class (outside functions, so it is available inside all functions)

Comment: Oh, and it gives me a "Error 1 'GPS.devise.coordinates' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context" :/

Comment: Someone posted exactly what i needed, "using Me = GPS.devise.coordinates;"